# MemoryMappedFile and b-tree for cache application

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

This is just an idea, I don't yet have any code, I need some design advice. I would implement a cache ( non distributed in first instance ) by using the MemoryMappedFile in c#. I think it would be good to have a b-tree as an undelying structure, but this is debatable as well.
So the question are:

- Is B-tree a good strategy to use to fast search items when the undelaying support is a memory mapped files ?
- What tip and trick do we have with memory mapped files ? How much the view can be large, what are the drawbacks when it is too small or too large ?
- Multithread consideration: how we deal with memory mapped file and concurrency ? Cache are supposed to be higly hitten by clients, what strategy is better to have something performant ?

As @Internal Server Error asked, I integrate the question with this:
Key would be a string, about 64 chars max len. The data would be a byte[] about 1024 bytes long but consider an average at 128 bytes, or better: what I want to cache are OR/M entities, let's consider how long is a serialized entity in bytes with something like a BSOn serializer.

Comment: What is the data type(s) you are caching? What type is the key? How much data are we talking about?

Comment: key will be a string, consider something about 64 chars. Data vould be an array of bytes: a serialized entity, something from 4 to 1k byte probably.

Comment: why roll your own? couchdb, memcached, mongodb; apparently mongodb is _fast_

Comment: @sehe you are right, I know mongodb, but I want something embeddable in my  project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- B-Tree is good (with memory-mapped files), but if the file is not always entirely kept in resident memory then a page-aligned B+Tree is much better. [See also](http://idlebox.net/2007/stx-btree/).
- The trick with memory-mapped files is to use a 64-bit architecture so that you can map the entire file into memory, otherwise you'd have to only map the parts and the cached `read`s might be faster than `mmap`s.
- Try CAS (compare-and-swap) over the shared memory. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846327/257568).

Comment: Maybe there is something C#-pish for you at [nosql-database.org](http://nosql-database.org/). Or [some C project](http://highlandsun.com/hyc/mdb/) might serve as a reference.